# Osculating plane as limit of planes containing three points of curve

Tags: limits, differential-geometry, curves

Let $\alpha:I\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be an arc-length parametrized smooth space curve that is non-degenerate (i.e. $\alpha''\neq 0$). Fix a point $s_0\in I$. It is well-known that the osculating plane of $\alpha$ at $s_0$ is the limit of the plane containing three distinct points $\alpha(s_i)$, $i=1,2,3$ as $s_1,s_2,s_3\to s_0$. To state my question I shall review the argument.

Without loss of generality, assume $s_1<s_2<s_3$.

Let the plane determined by these three points be given by the equation
\begin{align}
\vec{n}\cdot\vec{x}-d=0
\end{align}
where $\vec{n}=(a,b,c)$ is a normal to the plane, while $d\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant. Note that both $\vec{n}$ and $d$ depend on $s_1,s_2,s_3$.

Now the key of the argument is to consider the function $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
\begin{align}
f(s)=\vec{n}\cdot\alpha(s)-d
\end{align}
Clearly $f$ is smooth. The assumption that $\alpha(s_i)$, $i=1,2,3$ lie on the plane means that
\begin{align}
f(s_1)=f(s_2)=f(s_3)=0
\end{align}
So we can apply the Rolle's theorem in single variable calculus to conclude that
\begin{align}
\vec{n}\cdot\alpha'(\xi_i)=f'(\xi_i)=0,\qquad i=1,2
\end{align}
for some $\xi_1\in(s_1,s_2)$ and $\xi_2\in(s_2,s_3)$. Then apply the Rolle's theorem again to conclude that
\begin{align}
\vec{n}\cdot\alpha''(\eta)=f''(\eta)=0
\end{align}
for some $\eta\in(\xi_1,\xi_2)$. Now take limit as $s_1,s_2,s_3\to s_0$ (so $\xi_1,\xi_2,\eta\to s_0$ as well) to conclude that the plane is parallel to the vectors $\alpha'(s_0)$ and $\alpha''(s_0)$, and contains the point $\alpha(s_0)$, hence it is the osculating plane of $\alpha$ at $s_0$.

---

Now let us take a closer look on the limit-taking process, which leads to my question. When we prove that the limit plane is parallel to, says, the tangent vector $\alpha'(s_0)$, we are really proving that the normal of the limit plane is normal to $\alpha'(s_0)$, which is done by taking the limit of both sides of
\begin{align}
\vec{n}\cdot\alpha'(\xi_i)=0
\end{align}
However, recall that the normal $\vec{n}$ is actually dependent of the points $s_1,s_2,s_3$, so when we take limit, besides having $\alpha'(\xi_i)\to\alpha'(s_0)$, we are also taking limit of $\vec{n}=\vec{n}(s_1,s_2,s_3)$. My **question** is:

> How do we justify that this limit $\lim_{s_1,s_2,s_3\to s_0}\vec{n}(s_1,s_2,s_3)$ exists?

Or equivalently, how do we justify that the plane really converges to some limiting plane?

One may consider choosing $\vec{n}(s_1,s_2,s_3)$ that can be explicitly expressed in terms of $s_1,s_2,s_3$ and compute the limit of the expression. One natural candidate is the cross product $(\alpha(s_2)-\alpha(s_1))\times(\alpha(s_3)-\alpha(s_1))$, but clearly this tends to the zero vector when $s_1,s_2,s_3\to s_0$, which doesn't help the problem. One may then consider instead the *normalized* cross product
\begin{align}
\frac{(\alpha(s_2)-\alpha(s_1))\times(\alpha(s_3)-\alpha(s_1))}
{|(\alpha(s_2)-\alpha(s_1))\times(\alpha(s_3)-\alpha(s_1))|}
\end{align}
which always has unit length, but it's not clear to me how to justify that this expression has a limit when $s_1,s_2,s_3\to s_0$.

Since this result is so standard in classical differential geometry of curves, I wonder if I'm missing something that's really simple. Any hint, comment or answer is welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Comment: The components of $\vec n \, (s_1,s_2,s_3)$ are the solutions of a linear system: so by continuity ....

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I'm sorry but I don't quite get it. I suppose the linear system you mean is $A\cdot\vec{n}=0$, where the rows of the matrix $A$ are $\alpha'(\xi_i)^T$ and $\alpha''(\eta)^T$ (viewing all as column vectors, so $^T$ means transpose). Do you mean to deduce from this by continuity?

Comment: I'm referring to a linear system like $f(s_1)=0 \land f'(\xi_1)=0 \land f''(\eta)=0$ .

Comment: By the way, the osculating plane of $\alpha$ at $s_0$ is the limit of the plane containing three distinct points $\alpha(s_i)$, $i=0,1,2$ as $s_1,s_2 \to s_0$. You should edit your post accordingly.

Comment: If you edit, the first equation of the linear system becomes $f(s_0)=0$ of course .

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I think if I modify my matrix A to have first row given by $\alpha(s_1)^T$ and modify the R.H.S. to be the vector $(d,0,0,)^T$ then we are on the same page. Still, may I know how does this answer my question by continuity?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Regarding the definition of osculating plane, I have always thought that my definition ($s_1,s_2,s_3\to s_0$) in the question is equivalent to yours ($s_1,s_2\to s_0$), for example Spivak's Vol II definitely uses mine. Some other texts do not define the osculating plane in either way but they define the osculating sphere also using three points. I am aware that your definition appears more commonly, e.g. in classics like do Carmo or Struik. May I know if there's any subtle difference between the two?

Comment: You know how the solutions of a linear system are done: they depend "rationally" on the coefficients .... here the coefficients are the components of $\alpha$ calculated in $s_1$, of $\alpha'$ calculated in $\xi_1$, etc. .... and $\alpha$, $\alpha'$ and $\alpha''$ are continuous.

Comment: I cannot say about Spivak because can't read his approach. Let's stop with comments. I'll write an answer, time permitting.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Ah, the rational dependence on the coefficients. How silly of me. Anyway, you are still welcome to write an answer. Thank you so much for the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the two definitions are equivalent if $\alpha''$ is continuous in a nighbourhood of $s_0$. One should verify of course.

Coming back to your main question, you can even forget my comments because from $f'(\xi_1)=0$ and $f''(\eta)=0$ you get directly (!) $\,\vec n=\alpha'(\xi_1) \times \alpha''(\eta)\,$ up to a constant factor so that the limit is $\alpha'(s_0) \times \alpha''(s_0)$ by continuity.

Note that, if $\,\alpha'(s_0) \times \alpha''(s_0) \neq 0$, then $\alpha'\times \alpha'' \neq 0$ in a neighbourhood of $s_0$ by continuity.

Comment: Sorry but may I know how do we get $\vec{n}=\alpha'(\xi_1)\times\alpha''(\eta)$? I would think that this holds if and only if $\alpha'(\xi_1)$ and $\alpha''(\eta)$ are linearly independent, but this seems not very direct to me...

Comment: I also have another question: Since I also have $f'(\xi_2)=0$, can I conclude that $\vec{n}=\alpha'(\xi_1)\times\alpha'(\xi_2)$ up to a constant factor? but this limit is $\alpha'(s_0)\times\alpha'(s_0)=0$ though...

Comment: @Hopfeccentric If $\,\alpha(s_1),\,\alpha(s_2),\,\alpha(s_3)\,$ are non-collinear, then $\,\alpha'(\xi_1)$ and $\alpha''(\eta)$ are linearly independent. Otherwise the $3\times4$ matrix of the linear system wouldn't have rank $3$ as it must be instead because there is a unique plane on $\,\alpha(s_1),\,\alpha(s_2),\,\alpha(s_3)\,$.

Comment: @Hopfeccentric Remember $\vec n$ must satisfy $f''(\eta)=0$ also.